# the click function is removing all changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a Click function , inside it ajax post method, 
this method is getting info from database 
after i click the button the info show up for 1 second and then they vanish .
this is the code

```
$('.ViewVisitorMsg').click(function() {
    var requestsID = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: baseURL + "admin/Messenger/get_messages_to_admin",
        data: {
            request_id:requestsID
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].sender == 1) {
                    chatBox.append("<li  class= 'clearfix'><div class='message-data align-right'></div><div class='message other-message float-right'>" + data[i].message + "</div></li>");
                } else {
                    chatBox.append("<li><div class='message-data'><span class='message-data-name'> Vincent</span></div><div class='message my-message'>" + data[i].message + "</div></li>");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

i tried to put manually one ID and it works. 
it's like when the click function finish , it resets all variables

EDIT: 
it's  link not a form

Comment: Is the element you are clicking related to a form (or a link)?  You are not cancelling the form submit if so, which would cause the page to perform a page transfer and wipe out what your ajax does.

Comment: Check the docs for [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) Its likely running your click and then the form is being submitted (if the `ViewVisitorMsg` would normally have submitted the form)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably clicking on a `button` inside a `form` which is interpreted as a submit button (`<button type="submit">`), which will submit the form and refresh the page. Change the button to `<button type="button">` to prevent it from submitting the form.